# What is the easiest way to save data of application even after closing it

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to use a data saving feature in several of my simple winform apps. Is there a way to simply save a value of variables somewhere (Database, Textfile) and load it after each start of the app?

And what is the simplest way to do so?

Comment: Well, you can save data as the form closes in the FormClosed event. You cannot save anything after the _application_ has closed as the data will be gone by then. As for how to do it, that depends a lot on what form the data is in. You'll need to be much more specific.

Comment: Let's say I wanna make a dictionary app, in which user saves words and their translation, and wants them to load and check them even after closing the app.

Comment: Read up on the Dictionary type and on serialization.

Answer (score 3):

There are too many ways to save your data after closing, some of them :

- **Settings**

to add it programmatically, you can do :

```
System.Configuration.SettingsProperty property = new System.Configuration.SettingsProperty("Sample1");
Properties.Settings.Default["Sample1"] = SomeStringValue;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

- **Database**
  You can save your data in database tables if they are large
- **XML File**
  if you have a medium embedded data the xml file is the way to go.

Finally, its all depends on what data you want to store.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the options below

1. Use the settings that come with visual studio to save your variable and load them back when you start the app the next time.Like below

   Go to your project properties and go to settings    then add a new settings . You can add as many settings as you want using the settings designer. They can be of different variable types (string, color,into,etc)

To change a setting from code, use

```
 //we created a setting named 'mysetting' of type to string 
Properties.Settings.Default.mysetting = "test string";
//Save the setting 
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
//To get the value of a setting, use
string mystr = Properties.Settings. Default.mysetting;
```

2. You can simply write the value of the variable to a text file and read it back on startup.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest solution for your would be to use the [Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings) which inside Visual Studio, you can easily do much of the work in the design time as well.

> Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, you can create and access values
>   that are persisted between application execution sessions. These
>   values are called settings. Settings can represent user preferences,
>   or valuable information the application needs to use. For example, you
>   might create a series of settings that store user preferences for the
>   color scheme of an application. Or you might store the connection
>   string that specifies a database that your application uses. Settings
>   allow you to both persist information that is critical to the
>   application outside the code, and to create profiles that store the
>   preferences of individual users.

Read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Configuration.Settings which will save your configs into YourProgram.exe.config in xml format, but YOU WILL NEED TO CALL Save() MANUALLY TO SAVE THE MODIFIED CONFIG. In .Net programming, I consider it very convenient.

You can also define your own config file, a simple approach can be using json.

Another approach is to use a local database like sqlite(recommended) or access(less recommended) an define a table called 'config' to save all your config fields.

The least recommended approach is to save your config into windows registery.WHICH WILL MAKE YOUR USER VERY ANNOYED.